# Why are numbers appearing black in Atom IDE

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom IDE, with the Atom Dark theme active, numbers appear black sometimes, making them hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

https://discuss.atom.io/t/any-numbers-i-type-in-are-in-black/39076/3

If this happens it's because Atom doesn't recognise certain fonts properly. In the `Settings -> Editor` panel, change the font to one that it does.

EDIT: For fancy fonts you can use https://github.com/braver/fonts